# Issue on get Facebook Friendlist in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the friends list from Facebook using the Graph API.i get the friends list for the first time when i run the app in device after that i get the result as null i don't know why.i use the following code to get the friends list from facebook

```
    new Request(FBsession, "/me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET,
            new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                    Log.v("Friends List from facebook;;;;;;",
                            response.getRawResponse()
                                    + ";;;;;;;;DATA;;;;;;;;;;"
                                    + response.getRequest().getParameters()
                                            .getString("data"));
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getRawResponse())) {
                        onParseFriendsData(response.getRawResponse());

                    } else {
                        onSetError("We can't find friends from facebook");
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

can any one please help me to sort out his issue

Comment: facebook doesnt allow friend list to apps , you can get only those friends which are logined in your app .

Comment: @TusharPandey: as per the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends)  it can be done

Comment: @Tushar Pandey yeah i know it already thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that:

**1.** you have correctly generated the app-id with OpenSSL and declared it in your application manifest.

**2.** application package name and app-id are correctly entered on your Facebook app details page.

**3.** you have applied for the relevant permissions and received them from FB.

**4.** the access token is valid (i.e. non-null).

**5.** the session state of the access token is OPENED.

The package name has to be exactly the same as that posted in your FB app developer settings when you applied for permissions and received them. When you create a release APK, that has to be signed with OpenSSL **AGAIN**, and the new id has to be updated in your FB developer settings.

Comment: zygoteInit Thank you very much,let me check with your steps and let you know

Comment: finally i got it , after login successfully i get the seesion and then proceed with the code to get the friends list, in previous i misplaced the code to get the session.after debugging i got that thank you so much.